# max-width CSS attribute not working on a DIV

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm wanting to restrict the displayed size of the image selected by the user, but am not having any luck with my CSS, am I doing something wrong?

The user can select an image, and it is being displayed, but it is showing the full size of the image so in some cases it extends far beyond the viewable area of the web page.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input id="fileUpload" type="file" />
    <br />
    <div id="image-holder" style="width:100%;max-width:50px;height:auto;border:4px solid"></div>
</div> 


@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")


<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fileUpload").on('change', function () {

            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {

                var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
                image_holder.empty();

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $("<img />", {
                        "src": e.target.result,
                        "class": "thumb-image"
                    }).appendTo(image_holder);

                }
                image_holder.show();
                reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
            }
        });



    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `max-width: 100%` to the `img` if you want it to be constrained to the width of the parent.

```html
<div style="max-width: 50px">
  <img style="max-width: 100%" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Is it possible to inline the CSS in the html &/or jQuery?  When I tried it, the image no longer displays.

Comment: @tbone sure updated the answer. should work just like any other inline style or using `$.css()`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than an img tag, set it as the background-image of the div with background-size:contain

```
<div class="imgDiv" style="background-image:url('some-img.png');"/>

.imgDiv {
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat
}
```

This styling will make it so the background size is contained within the height/width of the div, and centered horizontally and vertically.